# VLC creates blank video when converting with crop filter

Tags: video, vlc-media-player, troubleshooting, video-conversion, crop

I have an MP4 video I'm trying to crop using VLC media player.

I've followed the directions [here](https://www.joyoshare.com/video-editing/crop-video-in-vlc.html), but the **result is a file with only audio and no video.**

**What's going on and how do I fix it?**

---

**UPDATE**

I got the output video to work just fine by reducing the crop pixels (3rd image below). Once I set them all below 50, it created a cropped video. However, I tried iteratively cropping cropped videos, but by the third such instance, it quit working again (despite having reduced the crop pixels further).

- Note: I was removing less than 150 pixels of the sides in total and less than 200 pixels off the bottom. As you can see below, the video 1128x920 pixels.

---

Screenshots:

[image]

[image] [image]

[image]  [image]  [image]

[image]

Comment: Is using VLC a requirement?

Comment: "result is a file with only audio and no video.": Do you want to say that "Video is blank" or "The result file contains no video stream at all"

Comment: @mashuptwice VLC is the only software I have that can handle video cropping.

Comment: @SaaranshGarg I'm actually not entirely sure how to tell the difference. I just took a look at the details of the new video file (right click > properties > details). The frame width, frame height, data rate, total bitrate, and frame rate all show up as blank apparently.

Comment: @theforestecologist That is not true. You also have open source software: [kdenlive](https://kdenlive.org/en/download) [openshot](https://www.openshot.org/download/) [Olive](https://www.olivevideoeditor.org/) to name a few. Much better to use a by-purpose video editor for a task like that than using VLC.

Comment: @mashuptwice I do not have admin rights to install additional programs onto my machine. VLC is the best I was given.

Comment: @theforestecologist, 1. By what you told, looks like your file doesn't have any video stream at all. 2. Not all programs require installation. 3. You can easily do it via `ffmpeg`